# ElasticSearch: should I worry about scaling servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoid

I have to work on an auto-completion feature for my rails api.

From what I understand, installing [mongoid-elasticsearch](https://github.com/rs-pro/mongoid-elasticsearch) would make it work pretty much out of the box, which is nice :)

However I don't have (yet) a good feeling of what's happening under the hook. The default installation seems to run a es-api on the same server that runs the rails api.

Is this a bad/not scalable practice ? I know elastic-search will load the database -- which is fine -- but I don't really know what will happen server-side.

I'm talking about 10k, maybe up to 50k entries to begin with, and I would be delighted, NOT to see my app miserably crashing after I install elasticsearch ^^

Any thoughts ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you want advice about scaling you'll need to provide more information - current platform (windows, linux?), size and number of servers, query volume, insert volume, schema/mappings.

Comment: Are you already running ElasticSearch, or just looking for a solution for auto-completion?

Comment: I'm not running elasticsearch yet, so any other idea about building an efficient auto-completion would be appreciated  !